# Phoenix Views - Adding an options arg to View render/ 2, Issue with overriding render/3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Why do I get this error, when trying to add a param to a view render/2 method.

```
def render("show.json", %{post: post}), do: render("show.json", %{post: post}, [user: true, room: true])
def render("show.json", %{post: post}, opts) do
  %{
    # stuff
    user: if(Keyword.fetch!(opts, :user), do: render_one(post.user, App.UserView, "show.json"), else: nil),
  }
end
```

Error:

```
imported Phoenix.View.render/3 conflicts with local function
```

I assume if I’m conflicting with an importing function, that this is a bad thing to do. Is there a better way to pass options, or can I somehow fix this in another way?

Comment: Can you show the entire module? I get an error of `def render/3 defaults conflicts with def render/2` when I do the same thing.

Comment: @JustinWood I've updated the code. I actually don't use default params, instead of I have two methods. See above

Answer (score 1):

In Elixir, you can have functions with the same name, but different arity in different modules. This is why in our views, we can define functions called `render` with an arity of 2. `render/2` is the Erlang and Elixir convention for showing this.

With that said, Phoenix.View defines a [`render/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3) function. Which is imported in all views. So the Elixir compiler sees that you are defining a function with the same name and arity as a function that is imported into the module and complains.

The only real solution here would be to not call your function `render`. A suggested name could be `render_with_options`.